# MISRA codecheck suppress rule s24

Tags: c, misra

I am using MISRA 2004 and I need to suppress S24 rule, its generates around 900 errors in my project.

```
Error message: Use of "==" is not allowed in code.
Rule: S24
ToolName = codecheck
MessageType = Info
Requirement = N/A
```

Is there a possibility to use a suppress for this error ? EQ esym () ?
Thanks

Comment: The rules in MISRA-C aren't enumerated like that and there is no rule against using == either. This comes from some really weird coding standard or tool, not from MISRA-C. What tool are you using?

Comment: Its an internal tool build by my company. It includes MISRA, PClint and codecheck errors.

Comment: *Error message: Use of "==" is not allowed in code.*  Huh?  How can you check anything for equality without using the `==` operator?  "Did the user enter the letter Y?  I don't know!  I'm not allowed to check!"  The "Requirement = N/A" output is, umm, rather revealing about what rectal database that "rule" comes from.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add requested information or clarification. Please show some example code that produces this message. Althogh the message is not clear at all by itself, it may indicate a real problem in your code. As the tool was built by your company, you should preferably ask the creators for support. If the message is only forwarded from a called tool, then check the documentation of this tool. Unfortunately I don't know what exactly "codecheck" is. Maybe https://github.com/Ericsson/codechecker ?

Comment: Some companies have stone-age old but mandatory rules, especially in safety-oriented development. Some of them force you to use `EQ` or even `$EQ$` instead of `==` to avoid something like `if (var = 23)` that is legal C, but means something different than `if (var == 23)`. If this is the case in your project, I'm afraid you have to replace all `==` with said replacement.

Comment: @thebusybee The old = vs == bug was finally solved in 1989 when Turbo C started to warn for "possibly incorrect assignment". Now if someone is using a compiler which is _worse_ than Turbo C from 1989, then that's the root of all problems...

Comment: In this case a MISRA-C checker is used anyway, so it is should be impossible to write assignment inside conditions for that reason. No need to deface the code with some `eq`.

Comment: @Lundin Don't worry, all the compilers I use throw this warning, but the rule is hardly to eliminate. Even contemporary coding style guides require it. Lately I found some colleague's code `if (23 < var)`. <facepalm> However, I reject this rule whenever I have the chance.

Comment: @thebusybee It's really the same old story as the misguided [Yoda conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions) from the 1980s.